# What's the full name of "DBNum"?

Tags: excel

In Excel,  if the cell value is 123 and specify its custom formatting as `[DBNum2][$-804]General` then it will be displayed like `壹佰贰拾叁`. (in Chinese,it's a local number format).
The question is :
 What the **DBNum** mean? I think it's should be some word's short name. then what's the full name?
thx for your answer.

Comment: You have 2 answers now. Please be kind enough to accept any answer which you want to. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The actual meaning may only known by Microsoft Office developers. And we can only *guess* what the full name is.

The corresponding chapter introducing the equivalent function in [LibreOffice](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.1/he/text/shared/01/05020301.html#hd_id3158404) and [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref//com/sun/star/i18n/NativeNumberMode.html) just use the name `DBNum` directly, without any further introduction, even the table of mapping in LibreOffice says "DBNumX".

Moreover, you [can't find the definition of `DBNum` in Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/Search/results?query=dbnum).

Answer (score 1):

It is context which clarifies the name. Basically To display numbers using native number characters, use a [NatNum1], [NatNum2], ... [NatNum11] modifier at the beginning of a number format codes. DBnum is a native character modifier. DBNum is an identifier and has no expanded name. It is defined by usage

*emphasized text*"[DBNum2]" number type to convert numbers to Chinese uppercase.
Realize Chinese uppercase currency amount by using excel's [DBNum2] number type
Today's meeting budget needs to convert the final amount to Chinese uppercase numbers. I found that One can't find the relevant information in Excel help. We got a google look and conclude  that we should use the "[DBNum2]" number type to convert numbers to Chinese uppercase.
Some common usages are as follows:
1. Set the custom format in the cell format:
[image: dbnum1]

2. Use the TEXT function to convert:

[image: dbnum2]

Source Link https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=zh-CN&u=http://blog.zengrong.net/post/278.html&prev=search

By the way , EditGrid does not support [DBnum2]

**EDIT :**
Further related information

Displaying Numbers Using Native Characters
NatNum modifiers

To display numbers using native number characters, use a [NatNum1], [NatNum2], ... [NatNum11] modifier at the beginning of a number format codes.

The [NatNum1] modifier always uses a one to one character mapping to convert numbers to a string that matches the native number format code of the corresponding locale. The other modifiers produce different results if they are used with different locales. A locale can be the language and the territory for which the format code is defined, or a modifier such as [$-yyy] that follows the native number modifier. In this case, yyy is the hexadecimal MS-LCID that is also used in currency format codes. For example, to display a number using Japanese short Kanji characters in an English US locale, use the following number format code:

**[NatNum0]**

Try to convert any native number string to ASCII Arabic digits. If already ASCII, it remains ASCII.

```
**[NatNum1]**

Transliterations    Native Number Characters    DBNumX   Date Format
Chinese     Chinese lower case characters                CAL: 1/7/7 [DBNum1]
Japanese    short Kanji characters              [DBNum1] CAL: 1/4/4 [DBNum1]
Korean      Korean lower case characters        [DBNum1] CAL: 1/7/7 [DBNum1]
Hebrew      Hebrew characters       
Arabic      Arabic-Indic characters         
Thai        Thai characters         
Hindi       Indic-Devanagari characters         
Odia        Odia (Oriya) characters         
Marathi     Indic-Devanagari characters         
Bengali     Bengali characters      
Punjabi     Punjabi (Gurmukhi) characters       
Gujarati    Gujarati characters         
Tamil       Tamil characters        
Telugu      Telugu characters       
Kannada     Kannada characters      
Malayalam   Malayalam characters        
Lao         Lao characters      
Tibetan     Tibetan characters      
Burmese     Burmese (Myanmar) characters        
Khmer       Khmer (Cambodian) characters        
Mongolian   Mongolian characters        
Nepali      Indic-Devanagari characters         
Dzongkha    Tibetan characters      
Farsi       East Arabic-Indic characters        
Church Slavic Cyrillic characters 



[NatNum2]
Transliterations Native Number Characters      DBNumX    Date Format
Chinese          Chinese upper case characters           CAL 2/8/8 [DBNum2]
Japanese         traditional Kanji characters            CAL 2/5/5 [DBNum2]
Korean           Korean upper case characters  [DBNum2]  CAL 2/8/8 [DBNum2]
Hebrew           Hebrew numbering       

[NatNum3]
Transliterations    Native Number Characters    DBNumX  Date Format
Chinese     fullwidth Arabic digits         CAL: 3/3/3 [DBNum3]
Japanese    fullwidth Arabic digits         CAL: 3/3/3 [DBNum3]
Korean  fullwidth Arabic digits     [DBNum3]    CAL: 3/3/3 [DBNum3]


Source Link : [Common/Number Format Codes][4]
```

Comment: The question asks what the "DBNum" is (the full name), not its usage.

Comment: It is only defined by its usage. There is no separate definition for DBNum

Comment: @GenoChen Please see my edit. More details are mentioned and  and as donPablo has mentioned it is defined by usage. It's not like WB for World Bank

Comment: @GenoChen My edit  is still in progress we always give source link also apart from copy paste to quickly reply to your question.

Comment: @GenoChen Basically this question of yours is related to features of system which are generally considered oFFTopic. However I have attemped to provide you all possible details hoping that it will help you.If you are not happy ,  please inform, I shall delete my answer.

Comment: @skkakkar Sorry, I deleted my comment. But you can see the (edited) original question, "I think it's should be some word's short name. then what's the full name?". Your answer indicated what `[NatNum]` is, "NATive NUMbers", but didn't mentioned what `[DBNum]` is.

Comment: @GenoChen It's okay. Sometimes these things happen. `DBNum` ia label type of name or say identifier. It has  no expanded name. Its usage varies with its associated number like 1,2 ... as explained in the extract of articles posted. Hope no misunderstanding.

Comment: I‘m the asker , thank you. but I don't want to make some unnecessary argument. just be friendly. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I have been looking for a description of [DBNUM1] (lower case Chinese number), [DBNUM2] (upper case Chinese number, for formal numbers) and [DBNUM3] (1-to-1 digit to Chinese number conversion), the last being obtained from somewhere else.

There is also another format code whose documentation needs to be found.  An example is "[>100]#,000", which displays number in format indicated, but only if it is greater than 100.  Not sure the rule of formatting if not meeting the condition.  Not sure if you can specify multiple condition.

It is a pity that Microsoft does not give a complete list of format codes at a single place.